# Evaluate the time average of Mathieu functions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, special-functions, physics, periodic-function

I defined a function composed of Mathieu's periodic functions:

```
    a[t_, \[Rho]_] := 
  (-2*I*q*Subscript[v, F]*MathieuC[-((2*(-2*Pi*q^2*Subscript[v, F]^2 - q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho]))/
         (Pi*\[Omega]^2)), (q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho])/(Pi*\[Omega]^2), 0]*
      MathieuS[-((2*(-2*Pi*q^2*Subscript[v, F]^2 - q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho]))/(Pi*\[Omega]^2)), 
       (q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho])/(Pi*\[Omega]^2), (t*\[Omega])/2] + 
     \[Omega]*MathieuC[-((2*(-2*Pi*q^2*Subscript[v, F]^2 - q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho]))/(Pi*\[Omega]^2)), 
       (q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho])/(Pi*\[Omega]^2), (t*\[Omega])/2]*MathieuSPrime[
       -((2*(-2*Pi*q^2*Subscript[v, F]^2 - q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho]))/(Pi*\[Omega]^2)), 
       (q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho])/(Pi*\[Omega]^2), 0])/
    (\[Omega]*MathieuC[-((2*(-2*Pi*q^2*Subscript[v, F]^2 - q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho]))/(Pi*\[Omega]^2)), 
      (q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho])/(Pi*\[Omega]^2), 0]*MathieuSPrime[
      -((2*(-2*Pi*q^2*Subscript[v, F]^2 - q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho]))/(Pi*\[Omega]^2)), 
      (q^2*Subscript[v, F]*\[Rho])/(Pi*\[Omega]^2), 0]) /. {Subscript[v, F] -> 1, \[Omega] -> 1}
```

It is the solution of this differential equation:

```
`DSolve[{Derivative[2][a][t] + Subscript[v, F]^2*q^2*(1 + (\[Rho]/(2*Pi*Subscript[v, F]))*(1 - Cos[\[Omega]*t]))*
       a[t] == 0, a[0] == 1, Derivative[1][a][0] == (-I)*Subscript[v, F]*q}, a[t], t][[1,1,2]]`
```

but in dimensionless form. I would like to calculate this quantity:

```
v = (1/2)*a[t, 0.5] - (I/(2*q))*D[a[t, 0.5], t]; numq = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[v]^2]]
```

and eventually calculate and plot the time average of numq with respect to variable q as defined above:

```
averq = (1/(4*Pi))*Integrate[ComplexExpand[Abs[v]^2], {t, 0, 4*Pi}]
Plot[(1/(4*Pi))*Integrate[ComplexExpand[Abs[v]^2], {t, 0, 4*Pi}], {q, 0, 1}]
```

However, I noticed ComplexExpand does not really simplify here. And eventually the integration process generates the error message:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 0. +<<12>>+<<191>> has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,12.5664}}.
```

What should I do to evaluate and plot this observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly.

Using your `a`

```
v = (1/2)*a[t, 0.5] - (I/(2*q))*D[a[t, 0.5], t] // FullSimplify

numq[q_, t_] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[v]^2]]

averq[q_] := (1/(4*Pi))*NIntegrate[numq[q, t] // Chop, {t, 0, 4*Pi}]


Plot[averq[q], {q, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I mainly just added arguments to your functions.